# Is there a way in VBA to find a String in a Directory and then Loop?

Tags: vba, string, loops, directory

I have partially solved my problem below. Over the course of the day, I want to increment my files by 1.

Currently, I can just increment my files with the same name (same string) by 1 if Excel detects in `mypath` a file by the same name

My file, for example, will save as `Red 06-22-2019 #9` if VBA detects `Red 06-22-2019 #8` in the directory

However, I want all my files to increment by 1 (regardless of the same file name), detecting only a shared sub-string (the current date).

That is, instead of Excel detecting the same file name and increasing `mycount` by 1 (as my code below shows), I want Excel to detect within the same directory whether any file name with today's date (`mydate`) exists. If so, that file name will increment by 1. (The various file names only share the same current date, so I could in theory increment many different file names over the course of the day, each day)

So when I save a different file name (`Blue 06-22-2019`) that has a similar sub-string (the current date) to the `Red` file names, Excel will increment the `Blue` file name by 1 (because it has detected, for example, 8 "`Red`" files in the same directory in which I want to save the "`Blue`" file)

The `Blue` file will save as `Blue 06-22-2019 #9` (for this example)

I've tried to work in the loop many times, using many permutations, but I am a relative newcomer to this whole coding thing

And I couldn't find anything about detecting sub-strings on the web

Please kindly assist if you can :)

```
Sub helpMePlease()   
      Dim myfile As String
      Dim mypath As String 
      Dim mycount As Integer 
      Dim mydate As String            

      mydate = Format(Now(), "MM-DD-YYYY") 
      mypath = "C:\Users\Robert\Colors\

      'do some code here, like opening a workbook and translating data, etc.

      'now, to save the opened workbook I came up with the below code    
      'it says increase my file name by 1 unless file name does not exist within my path

    Do
          mycount = mycount + 1
          myfile = mypath & "Blue " & mydate & " #" & mycount & ".xlsx"     
    Loop Until Dir(myfile) = ""          

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myfile

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a wildcard in dir, such as Dir(mypath & "*" & mydate & " #" & mycount & ".xlsx"). In that case it will look at all files with the same date.

Comment: Thanks Alex it works, we "wildcard" mydate and delete myfile from Dir function, as that contains string that can change from one file name to the another. Appreciate it man

Comment: Loop Until Dir(mypath & "*" & mydate & " #" & mycount & ".xlsx") = ""

Comment: Edit, the wildcard * serves as a variant, so whatever sub-strings or sets of sub-strings will change from file to file, just replace the sub-strings with * in the Dir function